# ImportError: cannot import name 'docevents' from 'botocore.docs.bcdoc' in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

**ImportError: cannot import name 'docevents' from 'botocore.docs.bcdoc'

(/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/bcdoc/**init**.py)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 36, in <module>
    from awscli.help import ProviderHelpCommand

  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awscli/help.py", line 23, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.bcdoc import docevents

ImportError: cannot import name 'docevents' from 'botocore.docs.bcdoc' (/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/bcdoc/__init__.py)

[Container] 2020/10/29 16:48:39 Command did not exit successfully aws --version exit status 1
```

The failure occurs in the **PRE_BUILD**.

And this is my spec build file: **buildspec-cd.yml**

```
pre_build:
    commands:
      - AWS_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_VERSION=${COMMIT_HASH}
      - REPOSITORY_URI=${CONTAINER_REGISTRY}/${APPLICATION_NAME}
      - aws --version
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
```

The codebuild was working correctly and nothing has been changed.
Only stopped working.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Reading this [GitHub issue #2596.](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2596) i fixed my error.

Just before the PRE_BUILD section, I added this line to my buildspec-cd.yml file:

**pip3 install --upgrade awscli**

```
install:
    commands:
      - pip3 install awsebcli --upgrade
      - eb --version
      - pip3 install --upgrade awscli

    pre_build:
      commands:
      - AWS_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_VERSION=${COMMIT_HASH}
      ...
```

Comment: in my case i also had to `pip3 install --upgrade pip` before upgrading awscli

Answer (score 14):

For me it's a version issue. So, I fixed it with below versions:

1. aws-cli/1.18.105

Command: `sudo python3 -m pip3 install awscli==1.18.105`

2. botocore/1.17.28

Command: `sudo python3 -m pip3 install botocore==1.17.28`

Comment: whomsoever it may concern:
Please use any of pip or pip3 << whatever you have configured in your system

Answer (score 9):

In my case this error occurs running the command 'aws --version' on ubuntu 20.04.

And the solution was:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip uninstall awscli
python3 -m pip install awscli
```

Comment: Tried this on Ubuntu 20.04, which runs Python 3.8.  It didn't work - got the same error.    boto3 version is 1.24.45, botocore version is 1.27.45, and awscli version is 1.18.69

Answer (score 4):

Was getting the same error on Ubuntu 20.04, the answer from @vijay rajput did not work at the beginning, fixed by replacing pip3 with pip - `sudo python3 -m pip install awscli==1.18.105` and `sudo python3 -m pip install botocore==1.17.28`
Thx

Comment: Just a note - confirmed that this does work on Ubuntu 20.04, unlike some other answers.

Comment: This also worked for me on 20.04

Comment: this worked for 20.04

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade pip (not necessary but it's better to do otherwise it will throw a Warning message while running the second command.)

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Upgrade awscli (Necessary)

`pip3 install --upgrade awscli`

Add `sudo` in both commands if required to have root user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

pip uninstall botocore
worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agreed.  botocore is a core library within awscli, so this really needs supporting information.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error on Ubuntu 20.04 (though not in CodeBuild, I was running `aws lambda invoke`).  Installing the AWS CLI v2 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html) worked for me:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Comment: Tried this on Ubuntu 20.04 - still got the same error.  Versions: boto3 1.24.45; botocore 1.27.45; awscli: 1.18.69.  What versions do you have?

Comment: @Craig S. Anderson aws-cli 2.5.3, boto3 1.21.36, botocore 1.24.36

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, in Ubuntu 20.04, if you install the `awscli` using apt (`apt install awscli`), the version it will install is 1.18.69, which is not compatible with later `botocore` versions. To fix the issue, either install the `awscli` through pip instead of through apt (so you can install the latest, which does work as of December 2022 with 1.27.30), or downgrade the `botocore` version.  The last `botocore` which will work correctly with `awscli` version 1.18.69 is 1.17.63, which has a corresponding `boto3` release of 1.14.63.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, then installed awscli and boto3 using pip3.  I then looked at the versions installed.  From that I created the following, which seemed to fix the problems on existing machines:

```
sudo pip3 install awscli==1.27.140 boto3==1.26.140 botocore==1.29.140 s3transfer==0.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install awsebcli --upgrade
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

If you still see error like:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1573, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

Then run

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

as mentioned here: [AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830524/attributeerror-module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check)