# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

Recently I had to reinstall Python due to a corrupt executable. This made one of our Python scripts bomb with the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

The line of code that caused it to bomb was:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

I tried pip uninstalling and pip upgrading the *google-api-python-client*, but I can’t seem to find any information on this particular error.

For what it is worth, I am trying to pull [Google Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics) information down via an API call.

Here is an output of the command prompt error:

```
  File "C:\Analytics\Puritan_GoogleAnalytics\Google_Conversions\mcfTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apiclient\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import channel, discovery, errors, http, mimeparse, model
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 57, in <module>
    from googleapiclient import _auth, mimeparse
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_auth.py", line 34, in <module>
    import oauth2client.client
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 45, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 45, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _openssl_crypt
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_openssl_crypt.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1517, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1537, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

Comment: Have you followed [Google analytics python quickstart?](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py) for service accounts?  or [QuickStart python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/installed-py) for installed app

Comment: @Daimto I did in fact. My posting here was to see if someone had an idea of what packages I could verify if there were version differences I was fighting with. I at least assume thats the issue based on my small research since this happened.

Comment: X509 implies to me that you are still using the p12 certificate for the service account instead of the json key file for the service account.   If that is infact true.  Then i would advice you to fix the code so you are using the json key file instead of the p12 file.   "Its just easer and causes less errors"

Comment: @Daimto I am using the json file. After a few trials and error I did find that the error was due to conflicting cryptography versions. I was able to get it up and running. Woohoo!

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Upgrade the latest version of PyOpenSSL.

```
python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

Comment: If you are like me, be sure not to read over this part:
"Edit the crypto.py file and remove the offending line by commenting it out with a #"

Comment: what's the difference between using pip and pip3 here? should I do pip3 if using python3 and rpi4?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to give you the deserved feedback. thanks!

Comment: where is the crypto.py file located?

Comment: @JamesDraper just check the stacktrace and you should see the path to the crypto.py

Comment: Unfortunately pip is also failing with this error

Comment: I found it better to remove OpenSSL package entirely: `rm -rf <path_to_lib_python3.7>/site-packages/OpenSSL` and then doing `pip install -U pyopenssl`

Comment: **Commenting-out** the offending line or **deleting the whole package** seems harsh, but in this case they are **perfect**. The other options will probably cause more harm and may also trash the Python installation completely.

Comment: very bad advice to modify library.

Comment: what crypto.py file?

Comment: The upgrade seemed to work for me, but I'm not sure if this is a stab in the dark that happened to work. Does this happen for specific versions of `pyopenssl`?

Comment: Yeah not clear on where that file is. What OP should have said is "After encountering this error, look at the trace back report (The error message displayed) at the very bottom it should show the file path" like this ` File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3126, in <module>` or if you need to you can try and find it like this `sudo find / -name "crypto.py" -type f 2>/dev/null`. Also after doing this it does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: DId not work for me. I had to recreate a new venv .

Comment: I just upgraded pyopenssl in the python install referenced in the stacktrace and the error went away. Did not need to edit any files manually.

Comment: For me, I had an offending `cryptograph` package in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. Removing that fixed it. I installed `nostr-relay` which brought an other version in causing the conflict.

Answer (score 134):

As all the previous answers failed for me, I used the trick in *[module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'](https://askubuntu.com/a/1433089/497392)*:

```
sudo apt remove python3-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

And then after a reboot:

```
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

Comment: Logged in just to upvote you! Thanks

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me as well; Ubuntu 20

Comment: WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Comment: Works like a charm, this saved us so much time, thank you so much!

Comment: Had to login to upvote thanks!

Comment: worked for me too thanks!

Comment: This only works if you have internet on the host. Working on a closed off box, cannot do this.

Comment: True, if You do not have internet access, then You need to have a reference system, where pyopenssl has been upgraded. Do a pip freeze and then copy all the openssl related packages from the internet to a local media and install them.

Answer (score 68):

I also encountered this error while installing Flask and firebase-admin on Ubuntu 20.04. The following commands solved my problem.
First I removed OpenSSL using this command.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL
sudo pip3 install pyopenssl
sudo pip3 install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, while other answers did not.

Comment: Just need to replace the path for OpenSSL folder to the one on your file system. In my case, it was inside-

/Users/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! One extra note, if you're using venv, you'd want to delete the OpenSSL directory from <project directory>/venv/lib/python<version>/site-packages/OpenSSL rather than /usr/lib.

Comment: That's the best solution inside a virtual environment. Thanks!

Comment: This works in the conda environment too. Thanks1

Answer (score 34):

```
pip3 install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
```

solved all my issues.

Comment: When I tried this, I got an exception backtrace: 
`CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'`

Which is what we are trying to solve.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo apt remove python3-openssl
```

Comment: Hey mtwebster, thank you for your answer! The community would appreciate if you would provide more context to your answer -- for example, how exactly `python3-openssl` package might be related to the problems described in the question, and how it's uninstallation can help with it.
Also, while it's clear from the question that the author uses Windows environment, so your answer is probably not helpful to them, I appreciate it can be useful to Linux users (whom distributives are APT-based), if it would be more elaborate in explaining what the issue is and why it can be addressed this way.

Comment: This does work to fix the broken package situation where pip commands give the original error.

Comment: this did help resolve the error, but as @mingaleg suggested, whats the reason behind this? how does uninstalling python3-openssl get around this issue?

Comment: It solved the issue but how?

Comment: The most clean solution, I think

Answer (score 11):

On my [Ubuntu 20.04.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), I managed to solve the error:

```
CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK\r
```

by reinstalling the following packages:

```
apt-get --reinstall install python-apt
apt-get --reinstall install apt-transport-https
apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

I do not use pip as I received this error message using [Ansible playbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)#Playbooks) and wasn't able to reach the servers anymore.

Comment: After re-installation I needed to upgrade pyOpenSSL and cryptography as in [answer by  @Robin Sving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73932621/3123501) and it worked

Comment: This is more likely for python2

Comment: python-dev wasn't a package

Comment: This will downgrade from python-is-python3 to python 2. Not a great option.

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks !

Comment: FWIW This also fixed it for me on Debian 11 after one of my SSL-using packages randomly encountered this. I made the following modifications:

1. Use `python3-apt` instead of `python-apt`
2. Use `python3-dev` instead of `python-dev`

Answer (score 10):

For me, earlier answers can't help me as I meet this problem for all pip commands, even `pip3 -V`. But I solved it by:

1. Get the URL from https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/#files if you need the latest version.

   ```
   wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/3f/ea5cfb789dddb327e6d2cf9377c36d9d8607af85530af0e7001165587ae7/pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
   ```
2. Install pyOpenSSL from the [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) file.

   ```
   python3 -m easy_install pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
   ```

Thanks *[module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428181/module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check/1429674#1429674)*.

Comment: Please try the "sort by" feature of StackOverflow and reconsider the phrasing "above".

Comment: The other solutions' commands didn't resolve the issue, and `pip3 --version` was also broken with stacktrace output in the same way. I see the "offending" `crypto.py` at `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/localstack/utils/crypto.py` but didn't think that commenting out a line was a proper solution. This solution seems like the actual fix.

Comment: Interesting trick, however easy_install was not installed on my system :-(

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled into this problem this morning trying to install weasyprint after a system update and restart.   Commenting out the line containing

```
X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
```

in */usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py* resulted in a further error

```
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'
```

None of the suggested fixes would work for me.

- sudo apt remove python3-pip followed by sudo apt install python3-pip
- sudo pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
- sudo python3 -m easy_install pyOpenSSL-22.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- sudo pip install --force-reinstall "cryptography==38.0.4"

I found this [module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428181/module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check/1433089#1433089) but it didn't add to anything I already knew.   I found this [AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021155/attributeerror-module-lib-has-no-attribute-openssl-add-all-algorithms) but it comes with WARNINGS for people running on desktops and it causing significant system wide issues.

I tried upgrading OpenSSL via easy_install but the wheel could not be found and there was a depreciation warning. Eventually I came back to the comment by @Alexandr who said just remove OpenSSL with rm.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL
```

From here I attempted to reinstall OpenSSL but found it was already statisfied.  Maybe an older package was blocking and this was the root of the problem?

```
sudo pip install pyopenssl
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (19.0.0)
```

I then upgraded pip and was able to install WeasyPrint which I hope confirms I have solved this issue.

```
pip install pip --upgrade
Successfully installed pip-22.3.1

pip install weasyprint
Successfully installed Pyphen-0.13.2 ... weasyprint-57.2 zopfli-0.2.2
```

Answer (score 4):

The below commands worked for me...

```
sudo pip3 install pyopenssl

sudo pip3 install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you got this error when using pip, try this:

```
rm -rf <python_path>/site-packages/OpenSSL
```

The problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried upgrading pip and installing another version of `pyOpenSSL` from whl file, but that didn't work. The only thing that helped is removing the entire folder with OpenSSL module like that `rm -rf ...python-3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL` and then doing all the thing you need.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I tried all the other answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know why this works?

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip completely broken, as @sgdesmet propose in a comment, the only option to resolve this issue is

> "Edit the crypto.py file and remove the offending line by commenting it out with a #"

No other solutions work with me.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are more lines that are broken. Removing the entire package seems to be the best way out.
Snake wrangling -- it's a way of life!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `sudo` rights the `--user` option might do the trick:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py --user
python3 -m pip install pyopenssl --upgrade --user
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue using Certbot, the right version was not the latest, so :
pip3 install pyOpenSSL==23.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestions. Once I realized the issue was the OpenSSL implementation, I just upgraded it using [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) as follows:

```
apt-get install python3-openssl
```

This will resolve the issue system-wide as my Python environment is maintained by the distribution.

Comment: What distribution? A Linux distribution? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

To solve it, I resolved by taking the last line that mentions the installation of the OpenSSL library, removing the folder, and installing the previous version:

```
File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from OpenSSL import SSL, crypto
File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 34, in <module>
from OpenSSL.crypto import (
File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py"
```

```bash
$ sudo rm -rf /home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL
```

And installing version 22.0.0 which fixes this issue:

```bash
$ pip install pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If `pip` / `pip3` is completely broken and nothing of the other option work (as described by @DarkSkull), then the line in the `crypto.py` file that's causing the issue has to be deleted or commented out.

Here's an automated way of doing it:

```bash
python_openssl_crypto_file="/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py"
search_term="CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK"
cb_issuer_check_line_number="$(awk "/$search_term/ {print FNR}" $python_openssl_crypto_file)"
sed -i "${cb_issuer_check_line_number}s/.*/    # $search_term/" $python_openssl_crypto_file
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be more errors when this one's deleted.
You need to remove and/or replace the entire package, because it's a python/ssl version mismatch problem.

Comment: For me, this code worked. But judging by the number of answers in this thread, there is no one right way to solve this problem. Just take these answers as inspiration and try until you get it to work for you. Eventually you can post another answer here. 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers above I was able to solve the same problem.  I use pipenv to manage my environment. The issue arose after upgrading my cryptography module.

The fix (for me):

```
pipenv update pyOpenSSL
```

Comment: hell yeah dude, thats awesome

Answer (score 0):

For me, issue resolved by changing snowflake-connector-python package version from 2.7.1 to latest version in requirements.txt file of Azure function app.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case was an unneeded OpenSSL installed that made the conflict and broke/block pip. The problem was solved when manual deleting the OpenSSL folder within *site-packages* folder.

For example, I deleted this folder in venv:
venv/bin/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL

And fixed the pip issue globally:
usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL

Note: I found that due to this error, pip was broken and could not install or remove. After this solution, I could install new packages and import packages that may install new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the package

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL
```