# Attribute Error: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

ON a fresh OS install, I first installed firebase-admin and it installed fine. The I am trying to install 'pyrebase' but I get the above error. I followed this solution of editing crypto.py .....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73932621/10197813

Then I tried again installing 'pyrebase' but the error is the same. Can anyone help please?

Complete error stack:

> raspi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install pyrebase Traceback (most
> recent call last): File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 33, in 
> sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==20.3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')())
> File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point return
> next(matches).load() File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py",
> line 77, in load module = import_module(match.group('module')) File
> "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File
> "", line 1030, in _gcd_import File
> "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File
> "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked File
> "", line 790, in exec_module
> File "", line 228, in
> _call_with_frames_removed File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10,
> in  from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
> File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py",
> line 9, in  from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import
> create_main_parser File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py",
> line 7, in  from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line
> 23, in  from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import
> canonicalize_name File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 94, in
>  vendored("requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl") File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 36, in
> vendored **import**(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0) File
> "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File
> "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 664, in _load_unlocked File
> "", line 627, in
> _load_backward_compatible File "", line 259, in load_module File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
> line 50, in  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/**init**.py", line 8, in
>  from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1556, in
>  class X509StoreFlags(object): File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1577, in
> X509StoreFlags CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
> AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute
> 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'