# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' when running conda commands on AWS SageMaker

Tags: python, conda, attributeerror

I am working on AWS SageMaker and simply trying to run

```
conda env list
```

and getting the error

```
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

(Note that when I e.g. run `conda list` it works). I found multiple questions regarding this and tried e.g.

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830524/attributeerror-module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check).

However, I am still getting the same error.

Any help on how can I solve this?

FYI: the complete error message is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 81, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/download.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .session import CondaSession
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/adapters/s3.py", line 12, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    import botocore.client
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/client.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/shape.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 35, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 46, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import (
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1517, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1537, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/condabin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 152, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1371, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1126, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1137, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1207, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/download.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .session import CondaSession
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/adapters/s3.py", line 12, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    import botocore.client
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/client.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/docs/shape.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 35, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 46, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import (
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1517, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1537, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```