# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'

Tags: django, lib, pyopenssl

I have been getting this error anytime i run my project with (runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt)...I already installed the django extensions and pyOpenSSL

I tried running without the (--cert-file cert.crt), that one seems to work fine buh doesnt provide me with what I am looking for .

Answer (score 3):

You can try to downgrade the cryptography lib:

```
pip install --force-reinstall "cryptography==38.0.4"
```

Seems to be a temporary bug, fixed, but pending to release: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4527#issuecomment-1368871248