# I tried to update Anaconda Navigator from 1.1.0 to 2.3.0 and in the middle of the update, my computer crashed. Now Navigator won't open at all

Tags: conda, anaconda3

I had clicked yes on the pop-up that asked me to update Anaconda Navigator from 1.1.0 to 2.3.0. It had downloaded, and I got another Anaconda Navigator pop up that asked to reopen the program now. I clicked yes, and then my computer froze and stalled for like 10 minutes. I got impatient and forced a restart on my computer and now Anaconda Navigator won't open. I get a traceback error that points to several issues in my anaconda3\lib\site-packages folder.

The errors I get are:

```
`(base) C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\Scripts>anaconda-navigator

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
        p = generate_parser()
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 40, in generate_parser
        p = ArgumentParser(
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 117, in __init__
        self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 422, in plugin_manager
        from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .hookspec import hookimpl  # noqa: F401
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\hookspec.py", line 10, in <module>
        from .types import CondaSolver, CondaSubcommand, CondaVirtualPackage
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py", line 6, in <module>
        from ..core.solve import Solver
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 15, in <module>
        from .index import get_reduced_index, _supplement_index_with_system
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 10, in <module>
        from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 22, in <module>
        from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 28, in <module>
        from ..gateways.connection.download import download
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\download.py", line 12, in <module>
        from .session import CondaSession
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\adapters\s3.py", line 10, in <module>
        import boto3
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from boto3.session import Session
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 17, in <module>
        import botocore.session
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 26, in <module>
        import botocore.client
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 15, in <module>
        from botocore import waiter, xform_name
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\service.py", line 14, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\client.py", line 14, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\example.py", line 13, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\shape.py", line 19, in <module>
        from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 34, in <module>
        import botocore.httpsession
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 41, in <module>
        from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import orig_util_SSLContext as SSLContext
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
        import OpenSSL.crypto
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1517, in <module>
        class X509StoreFlags(object):
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1537, in X509StoreFlags
        CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
    AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

`$ C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py info --json`


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.



No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false


# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1124, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 57, in main_subshell
        p = generate_parser()
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 40, in generate_parser
        p = ArgumentParser(
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 117, in __init__
        self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 422, in plugin_manager
        from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .hookspec import hookimpl  # noqa: F401
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\hookspec.py", line 10, in <module>
        from .types import CondaSolver, CondaSubcommand, CondaVirtualPackage
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py", line 6, in <module>
        from ..core.solve import Solver
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 15, in <module>
        from .index import get_reduced_index, _supplement_index_with_system
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 10, in <module>
        from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 22, in <module>
        from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 28, in <module>
        from ..gateways.connection.download import download
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\download.py", line 12, in <module>
        from .session import CondaSession
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\adapters\s3.py", line 10, in <module>
        import boto3
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from boto3.session import Session
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 17, in <module>
        import botocore.session
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 26, in <module>
        import botocore.client
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 15, in <module>
        from botocore import waiter, xform_name
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\service.py", line 14, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\client.py", line 14, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\example.py", line 13, in <module>
        from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\docs\shape.py", line 19, in <module>
        from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 34, in <module>
        import botocore.httpsession
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 41, in <module>
        from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import orig_util_SSLContext as SSLContext
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
        import OpenSSL.crypto
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1517, in <module>
        class X509StoreFlags(object):
      File "C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 1537, in X509StoreFlags
        CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
    AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

`$ C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py info --json`


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.



No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false

#
# Please activate the conda root enviroment properly before running the
# `anaconda-navigator` command.
#
# To activate the environment please open a Windows Command Prompt and run:
#
#   C:\Users\PriBo\anaconda3\Scripts\activate root
#
# For more information please see the documentation at:
#
#   https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/`
```

After some googling, I had deleted the .condarc file and expected that to fix the issue. I ended up with the same errors. I then deleted the .anaconda file, and that still didn't fix the issue. I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling pyqt5, and PySide2. This still didn't resolve the problem. When I tried to update conda using the command line (in my anaconda3\Scripts folder), I get the same error I get when I try to open Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error by following this link:
[AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830524/attributeerror-module-lib-has-no-attribute-x509-v-flag-cb-issuer-check).
I can now open navigator again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following worked for me:

```
pip3 install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
```